# NSDictionary with 3 keys under a value, how do I get the value of one of the keys? Keep getting nil

Tags: swift, nsdictionary

So the NSDictionary is equal to this:

```
"-KNQ66QDmXXc2E8K-B4Q" =     {
    id = UDtAJcqsMbNWxwApTh75sEl9DN83;
    la = "";
    na = "Julie Chang";
};
```

putting dict["na"] returns nil. I imagine I need to have dict["-KNQ66QDmXXc2E8K-B4Q"]["na"] but how do I get the "-KNQ66QDmXXc2E8K-B4Q" value to do so. I want to get the "na" value.

Answer (score 0):

You could parse through the array with a for loop:

```
for (key, value) in dictionary {
    print(key)

    guard let value: NSDictionary = value as? NSDictionary else { break }

    for (k, v) in value {
        print(k, ":", v)
    }
}

// -KNQ66QDmXXc2E8K-B4Q
// id : UDtAJcqsMbNWxwApTh75sEl9DN83
// la : 
// na : Julie Chang
```